# Root password not recognized when attempting to install third party software on Ubuntu 13.04W

Tags: grub2, 13.04, kernel

Why is my root password not recognized when installing third party software on Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: I thought that there was no root password (or inhibited) when an Ubuntu system is installed.

Comment: What command are you using to access root? By default the root user doesn't have a password and you have to use sudo with your password.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses sudo and by default the root account is locked.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to enter the super user (root) mode:

```
sudo su
```

Then enter the root password.